# Getting the index of item in an array VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to get the index of the item in an array VBA, but I have issue getting it.

```
Const NoOfVol As Integer = 5
Dim vol(NoOfVol) As Integer
For Index = 1 To NoOfVol
   vol(Index) = Cells(15 + Index, 8).Value
Next
```

The array looks like this: (-2500,-1250,0,1250,2500). I am calling the function this way.

```
Function Find(ByVal Value As Variant, arr As Variant) As Integer
    Find = Application.Match(Value, arr, False)
End Function
posOfVol = Find(-1250, vol)
```

But the posOfVol = 3, when it should be 2. Not sure where my error is. Need some guidance on this.

Comment: I don't think your array looks like you think it does. Unless you have an `Option Base 1` statement, your array dimensions are 0 to 5, not 1 to 5.

Comment: even in the case, it should be 1 not 3. Not sure why it is 3.

Comment: How do you figure that? Your array is actually `(0,-2500,-1250,0,1250,2500)` since you didn't populate the first element and you are looking for an *exact match*.

Comment: Aside from `Option Base 1`, you can be explicitly in the dimension of your array: `Dim vol(1 to NoOfVol) As Integer`

Comment: And you can check bounds with `Ubond` and `Lbound`.

Comment: @Rory please add your comment as answer. Will mark it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is actually effectively declared as:

```
Dim vol(0 to NoOfVol) As Integer
```

unless you have an `Option Base 1` statement. Since your loop goes from 1 to 5, you never populate the first element of the array and it retains its default value of 0. Therefore your array is actually:

```
(0,-2500,-1250,0,1250,2500)
```

and since you are looking for an *exact* match, -1250 is found at the third position.